# Programmatically get a diff between two versions of a file in TFS

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm trying to write a code which, given a path to an item in the TFS repository and two revisions, would compute a difference between the contents file had at these two moments. For now the code might look like this:

```
using (var projectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(repositoryUrl)))
{
    projectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
    var versionControlServer = (VersionControlServer)projectCollection.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));

    string path = "$/MyProject/path/to/file.xml"

    var before = new DiffItemVersionedFile(versionControlServer, path, VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec(minRevision.ToString(), null));
    var after = new DiffItemVersionedFile(versionControlServer, path, VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec(maxRevision.ToString(), null));

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        var options = new DiffOptions();
        options.Flags = DiffOptionFlags.EnablePreambleHandling;
        options.OutputType = DiffOutputType.Unified;
        options.TargetEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        options.SourceEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        options.StreamWriter = writer;
        Difference.DiffFiles(versionControlServer, before, after, options, path, true);
        writer.Flush();

        var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var diff = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

But once this code is executed, the variable `diff` is an empty string even though I know for sure the file has been modified between `minRevision` and `maxRevision`.

This code will also throw an exception if the file didn't exist at `minRevision` or was deleted in `maxRevision`, but this seems to be a problem to solve later, once I get this thing working with files which were only edited.

### EDIT

Having checked temp files, I'm sure both versions of the file are downloaded correctly. Something is wrong with the computation of the diff or with writing the diff to a stream or with copying the diff to a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved. The problem was the reader. After I changed the last two lines to

```
var diff = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
```

I got some diff at last.

Comment: TFS stores the file encoding - instead of assuming UTF8 it might be useful to use that instead.

Answer (score 3):

I know you accepted your answer, and this was asked in 2012, but I recently had to do the same thing, but much prefer using a `StreamReader` vs `.ToArray()`

The answer is that you have to reset the `MemoryStream` before you start reading from it.

add this

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

right after you flush the writer

Comment: Thanks, I guess it was the most direct answer to my. However, I still stand by my solution. `ToArray()` and `GetString()` will copy the data twice. But `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` internally uses a `StringBuilder` ([link](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Text/StringBuilder@cs/1305376/StringBuilder@cs)) so it copies the data twice as well.  But in theory my solution should perform better, because `ToArray()` knows the size of the memory stream while `StreamReader` doesn't, so it may need to grow the buffer as it goes.

Comment: @kamilk, good point about growing the buffer.  I wanted StreamReader for its very convenient .ReadLine()